# Cloudformation fails with "AMI cannot be described"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

I made a change to my cloudformation template, just adding mappings, and userdata in the AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration,
and now it fails to create my stack with the message "AMI cannot be described".

Any idea why? Google does bring much help here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The AMI was deleted by another user at the same time I did my edits.

The message "AMI cannot be described" actually means "AMI could not be found".

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for sharing it actually means 'could not be found'.

In my case, it turned out one AWS account had no permission to pull the AMI hosted in another AWS account. Adding permissions solved the issue. Perhaps this info is helpful for others.